syslog-ng adds a prefix to syslog messages
I have a squid proxy logging access logs to a file and syslog-ng reading those logs and based on squid's action it sets a severity - either info or notice - and forwards that as a syslog message to a NetXMS server. The problem is that the NetXMS server receives the messages like this:
1 2024-04-17T11:13:11+02:00 vvsrv-proxy1 1713345191.357 - - [meta sequenceId="5336"]     69 10.30.108.14 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3530 CONNECT api.github.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/140.82.121.5 -


(The empty line isn't a formatting error.)
I'd like to forward the lines as-is from the file to NetXMS, so like this:
1713345191.357 69 10.30.108.14 TCP_TUNNEL/200 3530 CONNECT api.github.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/140.82.121.5 -

The current syslog-ng config (excluding the default parts):
source s_squid {
    file ("/var/log/squid/access.log");
};

filter f_squid_denied {
        message ("TCP_DENIED");
};

destination d_squid {
        syslog ("10.0.0.254" transport("udp") port(514) template("${MSG}"));
};

log {
    source (s_squid);
    filter (f_squid_denied);
    rewrite { set_severity("notice"); };
    destination (d_squid);
};

log {
    source (s_squid);                                                                          
    rewrite { set_severity("info"); };
    destination (d_squid);                                                                   
};

Version info:
syslog-ng 4 (4.1.1)
Config version: 4.0

When I tried to solve it myself I found that incorrect syslog headers from the source can cause the relaying syslog-ng server to add it's own header, but in my case the source is a local file. I also tried to switch to the legacy network driver - instead of syslog - but it was still the same.
When I used rsyslog to just forward syslogs to NetXMS it didn't have any extra data, so NetXMS is parsing and handling syslog messages as it should.
Update #1
After some digging in NetXMS source I found out from the date parsing method that it can only parse RFC 3164 syslog messages. After reading the syslog-ng docs about using the legacy protocol I tried the following:
destination d_squid {
        network ("10.0.0.254" transport(udp) port(514));
};

But it still uses the new RFC 5424 format.
Update #2
I was using service syslog-ng reload and that wasn't sufficient, after restarting the service it started using the BSD syslog format. After some tuning my destination now look like this:
destination d_squid {                                                               
        network ("10.0.0.254" transport(udp) port(514) flags(no-multi-line) template(": ${MSG}"));
};

I didn't change any other part of the config, but now all log entries have Notice severity instead of entries containing the TCP_DENIED substring.

Here is a more compact version in-line with the comment I gave on the previous answer.
@version: current


source s_squid {
    file ("access.log" flags(no-parse));
};

destination d_squid {
        network ("10.0.0.254" transport(udp) port(514) flags(no-multi-line) template ("<$PRI> : ${MSG}"));
};

log {
    source (s_squid);
    rewrite { set-facility("daemon"); };

    if (message("TCP_DENIED")){
        rewrite { set-severity("notice"); };
    } else {
        rewrite { set-severity("info"); };
    };
    destination (d_squid);
};

Notes:

I was using if() statements here, but that's just a syntactic sugar around a filter + flags(final);
I reused the same file destination for both use-cases, this is simpler.
The format you are sending now "<$PRI> : $MSG" is neither RFC3164 or RFC5424 syslog, just pointing it out. Unfortunately there's a lot of cruft out there that use non-standard formats.
the syslog() driver in syslog-ng was dedicated to RFC5424 style output, which is not what your destination expects. The network() driver is basically a means to transfer anything you please, as you can customize the entire message using template()
the file() source normally assumes that the message format matches the syslog format as well, which you correctly disabled using flags(no-parse)


The correct configuration looks like this:
source s_squid {
    file ("/var/log/squid/access.log" flags(no-parse));
};

destination d_squid_info {
        network ("10.0.0.254" transport(udp) port(514) flags(no-multi-line) template ("<30> : ${MSG}") persist_name("squid-info"));
};

destination d_squid_notice {
        network ("10.0.0.254" transport(udp) port(514) flags(no-multi-line) template ("<29> : ${MSG}") persist_name("squid-notice"));
};

log {
    source (s_squid);
    filter {message("TCP_DENIED")};
    destination (d_squid_notice);
};

log {
    source (s_squid);
    filter {not message ("TCP_DENIED")};
    destination (d_squid_info);
};

The solution was to use the template to format the entire message including the RFC 3164 header, but this requires two "identical" destinations so I had to add persist_name for both to be unique.
Update: I had to create two filters, a matching and a not matching for TCP_DENIED because the previous config sent duplicate entries for denied messages.

Just wanted to respond, but you beat me to it :) there are a number of ways to improve this. 1) you can use flags(final) on the first log statement, 2) you could use set-priority() as before and a single destination, reusing the <$PRI> macro in your template. That way you don't need 2 destinations.
